# How to perform free text search in bixby

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

Is there any way that I can perform free text search in bixby?

For example: If user says a totally different word then i need to break those input and search again and get the result to user. If user is asking where would i find Chinese Waffle and i search it but did not get any result so I will break the input value Chinese Waffle into two words and search each words once again and if found the result, will show it to user. Or if there is another way to solve this please let me know.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit on the "total different word" part, because the later "Chinese waffle" utterance seems you want to some kind relaxation with empty result research, and Bixby certainly can do that. But the "total different word" kind of confused me.

Comment: User can litterally say anything... What I want to find a word which I could catch and produce some result. That's it

Comment: In that case, you need to add training utterances to cover a broad acceptable NL input, but keep in mind only to a certain reasonable limit. For example, if a Yelp like restaurant search capsule, the utterance "Is it cold on Friday?" It is ok to get a result "I don't understand". But utterance "I want to find closest Friday" should be able to learn to find the nearest Friday.

Answer (score 0):

About "Chinese waffle" example.

Your capsule should capture **Chinese** and **waffle** as two keywords or search options and go through certain API call to get a search result. When the result is empty, you can relax the search, for example only use **Chinese** or **waffle** as the keyword like this in your action model:

```
output(SearchResult) {
  on-empty {
    if (size(searchKey)>1) {
      replace (searchKey) {
        intent {
           goal: searchKey
           value: $expr(searchKey[0]) // this will use the first keyword
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can find out more about [relaxation](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/modeling.modeling-concepts.relaxation).

Let us know if it helps, and have fun with Bixby!